# how to display Blob in the window avalonia

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui

I'm making an Avalonia program. I am receiving an array of bytes from a web api and I want to display them in a window as an image. But now nothing is displayed. What am I doing wrong and How to properly display a blob on the screen as an image?

```
public static async Task<Bitmap?> LoadFromWeb(Uri url)
{
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        return new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(data));
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while downloading image '{url}' : {ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so, i've figured out what is wrong and this code has solved my problem

```
public static async Task<Bitmap?> LoadFromWeb(Uri url)
{
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var photo= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>(data);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photo))
        {
            var bm = new Bitmap(ms);
            return bm;
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while downloading image '{url}' : {ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }
}
```